# asp.net modelstate get validation errors and exceptions at once

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have a custom filter that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute where we inspect ModelState.

1. On our model, we have data nnotations with different rules
2. Our model is also strongly types (decimal, for example) so when users supplies string value to decimal property an exception will be thrown.

Now, when user send model that does both:

1. Violates some data annotation rule (but no exception)
2. Sends string to decimal property (exception thrown)

then in our ModelState we get ErrorsCount only 1 and exception in it and in Keys (or Values) we only get a record for the property that has thrown exception and not the one that had regular validation error.

We obviously want to have both (all errors and all exceptions) at the same time since end user doesn't really care.
Is it not suposed to give both at the same time or we're doing something wrong?

Comment: An exception is not thrown by the `DefaultModelBinder` if a `string` is sent for a `decimal`

Comment: i am not sure what that means. do you have an idea how to solve the situation? thanks

Comment: It means that by default an exception is NOT thrown. Are you doing that in your filter? (you have not shown your code)

Comment: Well, of course its thrown. Its Newtonsofts JsonReaderException and it gets written into ModelState["PropertyName"].Errors collection so when you iterate errors in ModelState you can see it there. But that's not an issue. Issue is why other validation errors are not seen there as well?

Comment: I repeat. An exception is not thrown - it is handled by the `DefaultModelBinder` (do you really think a yellow screen of death should be shown every time a user enters a invalid value)

Comment: how could exception be handled if it wasn't thrown previously? of course its handled by binder, how else could it end up in ModelState errors? :) come on, lets be serious and not get into that kind of discussion. Exception is there, visible in ModelState, question is why is Exception the only one there and not other validation errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145947/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dee-zg).